# Empty constructor of Fragment called instead of newInstance

Tags: java, android, constructor, fragment

I experience some weird behaviour in an android app I am developing:

I have a class HintsMenu (snippet):

```
public class HintsMenu extends Fragment implements AbsListView.OnItemClickListener {

...


/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static HintsMenu newInstance() {
    System.out.println("HintsMenu.newInstance()");
    HintsMenu fragment = new HintsMenu();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_TITLE,"Hints");
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public HintsMenu() {
    System.out.println("Hintsmenu constructor");
}
```

This Fragment is dynamically used in an activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MainMenu.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

....

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(MenuEntry item) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    if (item.hasActivity()){
        ...
    } else if (item.hasFragment()){
        try {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            Class<? extends Fragment> cl=item.getFragmentClass();
            System.out.println("Calling " + cl.getSimpleName() + ".newInstance()...");
            Fragment newFragment=cl.newInstance();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, newFragment).commit();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is, that item.activityClass (code not shown) is set by the expression

```
item.fragmentClass=HintsMenu.class;
```

at another position in the code, and item.getFragmentClass() returns this value inside onNavigationDrawerItemSelected().
In "onNavigationDrawerItemSelected", a new HintsMenu is created using the cl.newInstance() call.
However, HintsMenu's newInstance method is NOT called, but the empty Constructor is.

So insted of the expected output

```
Calling HintsMenu.newInstance()...
HintsMenu.newInstance()
Hintsmenu constructor
```

I only get

```
Calling HintsMenu.newInstance()...
Hintsmenu constructor
```

If i do

```
HintsMenu.newInstance()
```

I get the expected output.
Can anyone tell me, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static `newInstance()` on `HintsMenu` is not [the `newInstance()` method on `Class`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html). You are calling the latter. For example, if you were to rename `newInstance()` on `HintsMenu` to be `newMenu()`, and you changed your `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()` implementation to try calling `newMenu()`, you will get a compile error, as the compiler will complain that it cannot find a `newMenu()` method on `Class`.

Comment: Also read this link if you still want to call static `newInstance` by reflection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8836299/in-java-how-to-use-reflection-to-get-a-static-method-and-execute-it

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to achieve, that HintsMenu.newInstance() is called? Or shall I move the desired code (Bundle creation) to the constructor (called by HintsMenu.newInstance). (I know the latter is disregarded by android guidelines)?